# Error: read ECONNRESET while invoking a rest API call in nodejs

Tags: rally

at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)

1.

```
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
at emitErrorNT (node: internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node: internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node: internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```